# Visual Studio C2085 on Array Definition

Tags: c, visual-studio

In a .h file I have an extern declare:

`extern const some_struct SomeArray[];`

In the .c file I have the definition:

```
const some_struct SomeArray[] =
{
1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc.
};
```

VS Express 2013 is complaining with a C2085, 'not in formal parameter list', which according to MSDN, means a function prototype wasn't declared before the definition, but this isn't a function, so I'm a bit lost...

**Edit: More detail...**

An entire .h:

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_H_
#define MYHEADER_H_

#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint32_t my_event;
typedef uint32_t my_state;
typedef my_event(*my_handler)(my_event, void *);

typedef struct my_table
{
    my_event   Event;
    my_handler Handler;
    my_state   NextState;
} my_table;

#endif
```

and it's .c(pp):

```
#include "myheader.h"
#include "stdafx.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    typedef enum TestEnum
    {
        A,
        B,
        C,
    } TestEnum;

    my_event functionA(my_event E, void *pointer);
    my_event functionB(my_event E, void *pointer);

    const my_table TestArray[] =
    {
        A, functionA, A,

    };

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: since its an array of structs, try putting the values inside {}

Comment: `typedef uint32 event;`

`typedef uint32 state;`

`typedef event(*handler)(event, void *);`
``
`typedef struct some_struct`
`{`
 `event   Event;`
 `handler Handler;`
 `state   NextState;`
`} table;`

Comment: Sorry about the formatting...

Comment: Are you sure that's the line the compiler is complaining about?

Comment: Which of the lines is the compiler complaining about? The one in the `.h` or the one in the `.c`?

Comment: well, that header, and that cpp file compiles for me. I also dont see the forward declaration in the new example. that forward declaration should probably 'see' the struct definition.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example of how to initialize an array of structs:

```
typedef struct { int a; char b; } A;
const A arr[] = {
    { 3, 'a' },
    { 7, 't' }
};
```

if that does not help you, show us a *complete* *compilable*
*minimal* example that exhibits the error

Comment: Edited original question.